# A HashTable optimised for a large in-memory storage

Tags: c++, object-oriented, hash-map

I've been making this pet project of mine which is an implementation of a HashTable for a very specific purpose: storing huge amounts of objects in-memory (think Redis). I ended up with this implementation in C++ which is in my opinion a very basic and generic Java-inspired HashTable using buckets. I'd   like to hear advice on what to do next to make those narrow optimizations and what approaches are the best to try out. Also I've strived to make my code in the spirit of STL, and I don't think I managed to do that properly (C++ isn't my main language, I actually come from Python).

You can clone the code with tests [here](https://github.com/Korbiwe/hash_table)  (github link, cmake 3.13 or higher required)

```
#pragma once
//
// Created by korbiwe on 2019-02-05.
//

#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>

#include "util.h"

namespace lib {

namespace {
using index_t = unsigned;
};


template<class Key, class T, class Hash = std::hash<T>>
class HashTable {
public:
  using key_t = Key;
  using mapped_t = T;
  using pair_t = std::pair<const Key, T>;
  using bucket_t = std::list<pair_t>;
  using table_t = std::vector<bucket_t>;
  using reference = pair_t&;
  using const_reference = const pair_t&;

  explicit HashTable(size_t capacity = 8, double load_factor = 0.75);

  T& at(const Key& key);

  T& operator[](const Key& key);

  void erase(const Key& key);

  void insert(const pair_t& pair);

  size_t size() const;

  bool empty() const;

private:
  void _expand_and_rehash();

  const bucket_t& _resolve_key(const Key& key) const;

  bucket_t& _resolve_key(const Key& key);

  size_t _capacity;
  size_t _size = 0;
  double _load_factor;
  table_t _table;
  Hash _hash_f;
};

template<class Key, class T, class Hash>
HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::HashTable(size_t capacity, double load_factor) :
    _capacity(round_up_to_power_of_two(capacity)),
    _load_factor(load_factor),
    _table(table_t(_capacity)) {

}

template<class Key, class T, class Hash>
void HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::insert(const HashTable::pair_t& pair) {
  Key key = pair.first;
  T value = pair.second;

  bucket_t& bucket = _resolve_key(key);
  bucket.push_back(pair);

  _size++;

  if (_size > _capacity * _load_factor)
    _expand_and_rehash();

}

template<class Key, class T, class Hash>
T& HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::at(const Key& key) {
  bucket_t& bucket = _resolve_key(key);
#ifdef DEBUG
  std::cout << "Lookup in a bucket with " << std::to_string(bucket.size()) << " elements.";
#endif
  auto found = std::find_if(bucket.begin(), bucket.end(), [&key](pair_t pair) { return pair.first == key; });
  if (bucket.empty() || found == bucket.end()) {
    throw std::out_of_range("HashTable::at");
  }
  return found->second;
}

template<class Key, class T, class Hash>
void HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::_expand_and_rehash() {
#ifdef DEBUG
  std::cout << "Rehashing at capacity "
            << std::to_string(_capacity)
            << " and size "
            << std::to_string(_size)
            << "."
            << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Load factor at "
            << std::to_string(static_cast<double>(_size) / _capacity)
            << " before rehashing"
            << std::endl;
#endif

  table_t temporary = _table;
  _capacity *= 2;
  _table = table_t(_capacity);
  for (bucket_t bucket : temporary) {
    if (bucket.empty()) continue;

    for (pair_t entry : bucket) {
      bucket_t& new_bucket = _resolve_key(entry.first);
      new_bucket.push_back(entry);
    }
  }

#ifdef DEBUG
  std::cout
          << "... and "
          << std::to_string(static_cast<double>(_size) / _capacity)
          << " after rehashing."
          << std::endl;
#endif
}

template<class Key, class T, class Hash>
T& HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::operator[](const Key& key) {
  bucket_t& bucket = _resolve_key(key);
#ifdef DEBUG
  std::cout << "Lookup in a bucket with " << std::to_string(bucket.size()) << " elements.";
#endif
  auto found = std::find_if(bucket.begin(), bucket.end(), [&key](const pair_t& pair) { return pair.first == key; });
  if (bucket.empty() || found == bucket.end()) {
    pair_t& default_ = bucket.emplace_back(key, T());
    return default_.second;
  }
  return found->second;
}

template<class Key, class T, class Hash>
bool HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::empty() const {
  return _size == 0;
}

template<class Key, class T, class Hash>
size_t HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::size() const {
  return _size;
}

template<class Key, class T, class Hash>
void HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::erase(const Key& key) {
  bucket_t& bucket = _resolve_key(key);
  auto found = std::find_if(bucket.begin(), bucket.end(), [&key](const pair_t& pair) { return pair.first == key; });
  if (bucket.empty() || found == bucket.end()) {
    throw std::out_of_range("HashTable::erase");
  }
  bucket.erase(found);
}

template<class Key, class T, class Hash>
const typename HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::bucket_t& HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::_resolve_key(const Key& key) const {
  return _table[_hash_f(key) % _capacity];
}

template<class Key, class T, class Hash>
typename HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::bucket_t& HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::_resolve_key(const Key& key) {
  return _table[_hash_f(key) % _capacity];
}

}; // end namespace lib
```

Comment: What's in `"util.h"`?

Comment: Just the round_up_to_power_of_two() function, nothing else. It's pretty trivial, thought it would be redundant to include the code.

Comment: Even if you don't want that part reviewed, it can be helpful to reviewers if you provide it and the unit tests - we can make better suggestions when we can compile and run the code.  It's not a requirement, but can get you better reviews!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing includes:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

#ifdef DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#endif
```

Also, `std::size_t` is misspelt throughout.

---

We seem to be missing `const` overloads for `at()` and `operator[]`.  They are certainly worth having.

---

There's a few instances of the code to find a particular key within a bucket:

```
auto found = std::find_if(bucket.begin(), bucket.end(),
                          [&key](const pair_t& pair) { return pair.first == key; });
```

(my linebreak added for legibility).

It's probably worth refactoring that into a small function of its own (remember that it's almost certainly going to be inlined, making no change to the object code).

That's frequently followed by

```
  if (bucket.empty() || found == bucket.end()) {
```

There's no value in the `bucket.empty()` test - if the bucket was empty, then `found` will inevitable be `bucket.end()`.  (There's no benefit to moving the `bucket.empty()` test before the `std::find_f()`; just remove it).

---

We could make the member function signatures much easier to read by including the definitions within the class body.  For example, compare this:

> ```
> template<class Key, class T, class Hash>
> const typename HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::bucket_t& HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::_resolve_key(const Key& key) const {
>   return _table[_hash_f(key) % _capacity];
> }
>
> template<class Key, class T, class Hash>
> typename HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::bucket_t& HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::_resolve_key(const Key& key) {
>   return _table[_hash_f(key) % _capacity];
> }
> ```

with:

```
private:

    const bucket_t& _resolve_key(const Key& key) const
    {
        return _table[_hash_f(key) % _capacity];
    }

    bucket_t& _resolve_key(const Key& key)
    {
        return _table[_hash_f(key) % _capacity];
    }
```

---

To reduce copying, I think `insert()` should take its argument by value, and then `std::move()` it:

```
void HashTable<Key, T, Hash>::insert(HashTable::pair_t pair)
{
    bucket_t& bucket = _resolve_key(pair.first);
    bucket.push_back(std::move(pair));
```

In passing, should `insert()` allow us to add elements with keys that are already in the bucket?  That's not what `std::unordered_map::insert()` does.

`_expand_and_rehash()` is another function where we could usefully move instead of copying.  We should be able to get the whole class working with move-only types; it's worth adding tests that instantiate and use the class with `T` as (say) `std::unique_ptr` and dealing with copies until that works.

---

Since this is intended to hold "huge amounts" of entries, we really need a `reserve()` member, for those cases where we construct before knowing how many elements we'll add (e.g. when a `HashTable` is a member of some other object).

Consider the usage pattern (mainly the mix of insert, lookup, and erase) to decide whether `std::list` is the appropriate type for `bucket_t`.  We might want to implement our own (perhaps a "chunked list", for example, to reduce the number of individual allocations).

---

It's just style, but I'm not a big fan of prefixing the private members with `_`.  It makes the code look like Python rather than C++, and hurts readability.

I have a simple theory that if we need a mnemonic to keep track of which identifiers are which, then there's probably too much in the class and we need to think about splitting its responsibilities.

---

Final thought: I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I don't see anything here that makes this class any more suitable than `std::unordered_map` for "huge numbers of objects".  That suggests we need to add some comments to point out the adaptations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your review! I agree with all of your points, but have a thing to point out: it doesn't have specific adaptations for big numbers of stored objects because I didn't yet add them. That was the point of the question -- to get advice on what to do next to make those adaptations, what are the possible ways to make them?

Comment: Also, what would be your advice about private class members? Is it a bad sign if I tend to have public data members (I tend not to, but that was the point of underscoring the private ones, to distinguish them from the public ones)? If it is, then I agree with you fully, since I've been thinking about that for a while and underscoring private members is just really a bad habit of mine.

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor, you can construct `_table` with just `_table(capacity)`.

In `_expand_and_rehash`, you're making copies of vectors you don't need to make.  First, you can move `table` to `temporary` using `table_t temporary = std::move(table);`.  When copying the data to the new table, you're creating copies of the lists.  Use a rerefences in those loop:  `for (const bucket_t &bucket : temporary)` and `for (const pair_t &entry : bucket)`.  Then replace `new_bucket.push_back` with `new_bucket.emplace_back`, which will avoid another potential copy.

You might be able to defer the check for a rehash which is made in `insert` to the next insert.  (i.e., check for if a rehash is necessary at the start of `insert`, rather than at the end.)  The downside is that you wouldn't be able to insert an object already in the HashTable.  Which brings up an important point:  you currently allow duplicates.  If you insert the same thing twice, you'll get two copies of that key in the HashTable.  Is that what you want?  (`erase` will delete the first one it finds if there is more than one.)

There's no need to check `bucket.empty()` after your various calls to `find_if`, since if the bucket is empty the `find_if` won't find what you're looking for and will return `bucket.end()` (which you're already checking for).

In `insert`, you can remove the local `value` variable, which is unused.  There's no real reason to have `key` in there, either, since it is only used once.